# Order of persisted list field on JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

It's feasible for `JPA 2.x` to persist list-typed field below,

```java
@ElementCollection
private List<String> list;
```

Does `JPA 2.x` further prescribe to retain the order of the elements in the persisted list after it is queried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How they are returned is dependent on the database unless there is an order field in the table.  See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Order_Column_.28JPA_2.0.29 on the orderColumn annotation

Comment: i`ve looked into your referred wikibook paragraphs. Why is the `index` field of `employee_phone` table not with values `[0,2,1,3]` but `[0,1,0,1]`? How can the latter suffice to hint the order of the `phone` list?

Comment: Because the table contains many employee's phone references.  Each employee has its own list order, where the first phone will be in position 0 in that list.  So each Employee with a phone will have a record in that table with an index of 0.

Comment: Thanks. It's about `one-employee-to-many-ordered-phones`, so just another possible `employee_phone` table could contain columns like `employee_id [1,1,1,2]`, `phone_id [4,3,2,1]` and `index [2,1,0,0]`.